# What's the resultant angular velocity of a (2D) rigid body after it splits in two

Tags: simulation, physics, game-physics

If I have a single rigid body and it breaks into two pieces. What is the angular velocity of the two pieces after the split.

Before the split the rigid body has mass, m0, angular velocity w0, and inertia, i0 and center of mass c0. After the split we can calculate the two new center of masses, c1 and c2, and the new inertia values i1 and i2. This question is: how to figure out the angular velocities (w1, w2) using conservation of momentum and kinetic energy.

Comment: So the split is arbitrary, and I can figure out the new center of masses and inertia, then due to conservation of momentum the velocities should "balance" the mass distribution. Just a matter of figuring out the right formula!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

w<sub>2</sub> = w<sub>1</sub> = w<sub>0</sub>

The trick is to imagine the original body as the two smaller bodies joined by a massless arm. Then dissolve the arm -- and notice that this does not apply any angular impulse to either body.

(Don't forget that angular momentum must be defined with respect to a particular axis.)

Comment: I don't think this is correct. The angular momentum is not conserved with the above formula. I think both bodies will speed up a bit due to mass moving closer to a center of rotation.

Comment: @TomLarkworthy: **Angular momentum must be defined with respect to a particular axis.** if you jump to a different axis, you should not expect to get the same angular momentum.

Comment: Yeah took me a while to fully digest, nice one, thanks a lot